# Pagination not working when adding AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP-based pagination system and it is working fine, I'm using GET parameters to pass the page number:

```
    <?php 
$db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
$numrows = $row[0];
$rowsperpage = 2;
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);
if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) {
   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['page'];
} else {
   $currentpage = 1;
}
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
}
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   $currentpage = 1;
}
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM internet_security ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$startrow = ($currentpage-1) * $rowsperpage;

?>
```

and the way I show links is this:

```
    h3>Results <?php echo ($startrow+1) ?> - <?php echo min($startrow + $rowsperpage, $row) ?> of <?php echo ($totalpages *$rowsperpage) ?></h3>
<ul><?php 
if ($currentpage!=$totalpages) {
echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$totalpages'>$totalpages</a></li> ";
$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$nextpage'>Next&raquo;&raquo;</a></li> ";
}?></ul>



<ul><?php    
if($currentpage<$totalpages){
for ($x = ($currentpage - 3); $x < (($currentpage + 3) + 1); $x++) {
if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
if ($x == $currentpage) {
echo " <li id='pcurrent'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$x'>$x</a></li>";
} else {
echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$x'>$x</a></li> ";
}}}  
}

?> </ul>


<ul><?php
if ($currentpage > 1){
$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
echo " <li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$prevpage'>&laquo;&laquo;Prev</a></li> ";
echo "<li><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=1'>1</a></li> ";
}?></ul>
```

This pagination is working fine.

**My Question is** I now want to add AJAX functionallity to it so that i shoud have both functionality in pagination i.e if JavaScript is turned off, the pagination will work in PHP.

I tried this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#pagination ul li a, .temp').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#temporary').load($(this).attr('href')).modal();
    });
});
```

But now, the pagination isn't working and nothing is happening when the pagination link is clicked. What's wrong?

Comment: I have something similar to achieve and raised a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928368/paginate-records-on-client-side-issue/10929242#comment14290891_10929242".Please suggest the way i can apply it in my case.I have a separate select box for selecting no of records user wants to see on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is some confusion about what you are asking. As far as I can gather, you want to have both PHP pagination (when js is disabled) and AJAX pagination to take advantage of dynamic loading (when js is enabled).

In order to do that, you should do the following:

1. Put the code that generates your list into a function such as `generateList($page)`
2. In your php page, output the results of the above created function as your initial view.
3. Create an ajax_actions.php page that can call the function you created in step 1 and return the result.
4. Use the link click hander to call (via AJAX) the ajax_actions.php page and display the result. You will probably need to parse the page id from your link click and pass it along.

If you do these things, when JS is disabled, PHP will handle the pagination. When JS is enabled, you will do ev.preventDefault() and use AJAX to display the content.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes that's what i want both functionality, as you have suggested i will try it, also do you know any tutorial for applying this method, it will be great.thanks

Comment: I searched around and found this http://www.99points.info/2011/01/ajax-pagination-using-jquery-and-php-with-animation/ It shows you how to do the ajax part pretty well. Their implementation is AJAX only, so make sure you refer to my list above as you modify their example.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax will NOT work if JavaScript is not supported by the browser. Ajax stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML.

So now do you still want to support Ajax ?

If yes then confirm the following,

1. Is "temporary the container which has the listings and pagination ?"
2. What result the given url($(this).attr('href')) is sending ? It should return proper HTml, not having Document and body tags etc.
3. Have you checked your JavaScript error console and is there any error there ?

Instead of load , you can use ajax method which provides a function for handling error from server, you can see if server is returning any error.

Comment: You misread what he was saying: He wants his pagination to work with pure PHP if Javascript is turned off, but he is unable to get his AJAX methods working while Javascript is on.

Comment: i have php pagination in case javascript is turned off i just want to add ajax to it so that page load fast do you know the way to do it.

Comment: @maioran: "I now want to add AJAX functionallity to it so that even if JavaScript is turned off, the pagination will work in PHP."  This is the statement that's causing confusion.

Comment: guys my pagination is working fine in php, i want to add ajax to it now so that page load fast.

Comment: @Beenish Khan #temporary is the continer to show pagination result. pagination is in #pagination container. i am not as perfect to check errors from consol as you guys i am new and learning, i have posted my full codes see if you can suggest some thing.

Comment: and why are you using modal() ?