# Paginate records on Client side issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pagination

I am working on a search,filter operation using php,mysql.

My classes for pagination are

```
class Paginator{
var $items_per_page;
var $items_total;
var $current_page;
var $num_pages;
var $mid_range;
var $low;
var $limit;
var $return;
var $default_ipp;
//var $querystring;
var $ipp_array;

function Paginator()
{
    $this->current_page = 1;
    $this->mid_range = 2;
    $this->ipp_array = array(2,4,6,8,10,'All');
    $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
}

function paginate()
{
    if(!isset($this->default_ipp)) $this->default_ipp='2';
    if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
    {
        $this->num_pages = 1;
   //$this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
        $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
    }
    $this->current_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1 ; // must be numeric > 0
    $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
    $next_page = $this->current_page+1;
    if($_GET)
    {
        $args = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        foreach($args as $arg)
        {
            $keyval = explode("=",$arg);
            if($keyval[0] != "page" And $keyval[0] != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&" . $arg;
        }
    }

    if($_POST)
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
        {
            if($key != "page" And $key != "ipp") $this->querystring .= "&$key=$val";
        }
    }
    if($this->num_pages > 4)
    {
        $this->return = ($this->current_page > 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">&laquo; Previous</a> ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&laquo; Previous</span> ";

        $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
        $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

        if($this->start_range <= 0)
        {
            $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
            $this->start_range = 1;
        }
        if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
        {
            $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
            $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
        }
        $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
            if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
            }
            if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
        }
        $this->return .= (($this->current_page < $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All') And $this->current_page > 0) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">Next &raquo;</a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\">&raquo; Next</span>\n";
        $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    else
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring\">$i</a> ";
        }
        $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp=All$this->querystring\">All</a> \n";
    }
    $this->low = ($this->current_page <= 0) ? 0:($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
    if($this->current_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = 0;
    $this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";
}
function display_items_per_page()
{
    $items = '';
    if(!isset($_GET[ipp])) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
    foreach($this->ipp_array as $ipp_opt) $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'$this->querystring';return false\">$items</select>\n";
}
function display_jump_menu()
{
    for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
    {
        $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
    }
    return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page$this->querystring';return false\">$option</select>\n";
}
function display_pages()
{
    return $this->return;
}
  }
 ?>
```

I have performed a filter using check boxes like this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="checkbox1" value="<?php echo $suburb['suburb_name']?>" name="Suburb_check[]" onClick="changeResults();" onChange="" ><?php echo $suburb['suburb_name']?>  <span class="grey">(<?php echo $suburb['total']?>)</span>
```

Javascript/ajax code for filter

```
function changeResults(){
    var data = { 'venue[]' : []};
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            var chck1 = $(this).val();
            //alert(chck1);
            data['venue[]'].push($(this).val());

    });
$.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'process.php',
     data : data,
     success : function(data){
          $('#project_section').html(data); // replace the contents coming from php file
            }  
        });
    }
```

process.php file

```
include_once("includes/classes/db_connect.php");
include_once("pagination/paginator.class.php");

$pages = new Paginator();

$value= array();

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    $value[] = $venue[$key][$value];    
}
$countArray = count($value);

//echo $countArray;
/*echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);
echo "</pre>";
exit;*/

if($countArray=='2')
{
        $where = "cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[0]."' ";
}
else if($countArray=='3')
{
       $where = "cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and (suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[0]."' or suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[1]."')";
}
else if($countArray=='4')
{
$where = "cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and (suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[0]."' or suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[1]."' or suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[2]."')";
}
else if($countArray=='5')
{
        $where = "cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and (suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[0]."' or suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[1]."' or suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[2]."' or suburbs.suburb_name ='".$value[3]."')";
}
else{
    $where = "cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' " ;
}

$countSql="SELECT count(*) as total from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join suburbs on properties.suburb_id=suburbs.suburb_id where ".$where." ";

//echo $countSql;
$resultCount = mysql_query($countSql);
$data = mysql_fetch_row($resultCount);
$pages->items_total = $data[0];
$pages->mid_range = 2;
$pages->paginate();
echo $pages->display_pages();       
echo $pages->display_items_per_page();

$sql="SELECT * from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join suburbs on properties.suburb_id=suburbs.suburb_id where ".$where." $pages->limit";

//echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
//$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
/*echo "<pre>" ;
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>" ; */
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
      ?>
      <div class="projectlisttiger" id="propertyList">      

                <div class="spacer5">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="listnewimg flt">
                    <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php">
                        <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo ($row['property_cover_image']) ?>" width="186" height="125" border="0">
                        <!--<img src="admin/uploads/Cilantra1/1cilantra-large.jpg" width="186" height="125" border="0">-->
                    </a>
                     <!--<div class="newlistlaunch"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><img width="65" height="65" border="0" src="images/projects/kolte-patil/cilantra/new_launch_blue.png"></a>
                     </div>-->                              
                </div>

                <div class="listright">
                    <div style="width:498px; height:42px;" class="flt">
                        <div class="list-logo flt">
                            <div class="buildborder"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><img width="80" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Kolte Patil" src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $row['builder_logo']?>"></a>
                            </div>
                               <div class="tablistname"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><?php echo $row['property_name'] ?></a></div>
                        </div>   
                        <?php if ($row['property_price_min']!=0) { ?>      
                        <div class="listprice">
                            <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif"> <?php echo $row['property_price_min'] ?> Lacs - <?php echo $row['property_price_max'] ?> Lacs       
                        </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="listprice">
                             <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif">Price on Request
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </div>

                        <div class="spacer3">&nbsp;</div>        

                    <div class="listbox">
                        <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><strong>Address</strong>:<?php echo $row['locality_name'] ?>, <?php echo $row['city_name'] ?><br> <strong>Types</strong>: 2BHK &amp; 3BHK
                        <br><strong>Sizes:</strong> <?php echo $row['property_size_min'] ?> sqft - <?php echo $row['property_size_max'] ?> sqft </a>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-left:-3px;" class="flt">
                        <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><input type="button" value="View Details" class="detail_project"></a>
                        </div>     
                      <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><input type="button" onClick="showEnqForm('2659','Cilantro'); return false;" value="Enquire Now" class="enquire_project"></div>
                    </div>
                           <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>                                 
                </div>
                <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>              
       </div>
```

I return the paginated results back,but when I click on the page number it takes me to the process.php as the pagination class uses **$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]**
How can I paginate the results without changing the page url i.e using ajax for the same implementation. I can't make much changes and it would be useful if modifications in this makes it work.(That's why I have tred to add as much code as possible.) Sorry if its too much.
Thanks

**EDIT** 
**@Gavin Here is my process.php**

```
  <?php session_start();
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    include('processRegion.php');
    die();
}
include_once("includes/classes/db_connect.php");
include_once("pagination/paginator.class.php");
$pages = new Paginator();
            if(isset($_GET['dataString']))
               {
                    $regionValue =  $_GET['dataString'];
                    //echo "region=".$regionValue;
               }
else{
        $regionValue = $_POST['dataString'];
}
$reqValue = "'".$regionValue."'";

echo $reqValue;

$arr = explode(",",$reqValue);
//print_r($arr);
$getBack = implode("','",$arr);

$beds = "'".$_POST['beds'];
//echo ($beds);
$arrBeds= explode(",",$beds);
//print_r($arrBeds);
$getBedValue = implode("','",$arrBeds);
$finalBedValue = substr($getBedValue,0,-2);

if(isset($_POST['beds']) && $_POST['beds']!=" ")
{
    $cityNameAndRegionName = "cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and (suburbs.suburb_name in (".$getBack.")) and (properties_type.bed_type in (".$finalBedValue."))"; 
}
else
{
    $cityNameAndRegionName = "cities.city_name like '%".$_SESSION['$cityName']."%' and (suburbs.suburb_name in (".$getBack."))";
}   

$countSql="SELECT count(*) as total from properties inner join cities on properties.city_id=cities.city_id inner join suburbs on properties.suburb_id=suburbs.suburb_id left outer join properties_type on properties.property_id=properties_type.property_id where ".$cityNameAndRegionName." ";
    ?>
    <?php include_once("processRegion.php"); ?>
```

**processRegion.php** with HTML

```
<div class="flt width710" id="">
            <div style="float:right" id="toppagesel">
            <?php

            //Query processed here
        ?>
            </div>
                    </div>
        <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>
                <div><strong>Results for properties for sale</strong> in <?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['$cityName']) ?>.</div>
        <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>

         <div class="width710" id="displayProp">
        <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { ?>  
            <div class="projectlisttiger" id="propertyList">        

                <div class="spacer5">&nbsp;</div>
                  <div class="listnewimg flt">
                    <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php">
                        <img src="admin/uploads/<?php echo ($row['property_cover_image']) ?>" width="186" height="125" border="0">

                </div>

                <div class="listright">
                    <div style="width:498px; height:42px;" class="flt">
                        <div class="list-logo flt">
                            <div class="buildborder"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><img width="80" height="36" border="0" align="absmiddle" alt="Kolte Patil" src="admin/uploads/<?php echo $row['builder_logo']?>"></a>
                            </div>
                               <div class="tablistname"><a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><?php echo $row['property_name'] ?></a></div>
                        </div>   
                        <?php if ($row['property_price_min']!=0) { ?>      
                        <div class="listprice">
                            <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif"> <?php echo $row['property_price_min'] ?> Lacs - <?php echo $row['property_price_max'] ?> Lacs       
                        </div>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="listprice">
                             <img width="18" height="18" align="absmiddle" src="images/city/rupee_icon.gif">Price on Request
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                    </div>
                    <div class="spacer3">&nbsp;</div>        

                    <div class="listbox">
                        <a href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><strong>Address</strong>:<?php echo $row['locality_name'] ?>, <?php echo $row['city_name'] ?><br> <strong>Types</strong>: 2BHK &amp; 3BHK
                        <br><strong>Sizes:</strong> <?php echo $row['property_size_min'] ?> sqft - <?php echo $row['property_size_max'] ?> sqft </a>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-left:-3px;" class="flt">
                        <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="p-kolte-patil-cilantro-wagholi-pune.php"><input type="button" value="View Details" class="detail_project"></a>
                        </div>     
                      <div style="width:110px;" class="flt"><input type="button" onClick="showEnqForm('2659','Cilantro'); return false;" value="Enquire Now" class="enquire_project"></div>
                    </div>
                           <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>                                 
                </div>
                <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>              
       </div>
       <?php
            }
       ?>
  <div class="spacer15">&nbsp;</div>
</div>     

<div style="float:right" id="toppagesel">
            <?php 
                echo $pages->display_pages();
                echo $pages->display_items_per_page();
            ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does your pagination currently work using PHP alone? If so, you can use jQuery to handle the submittion of the form via Ajax. The only issue I can see, is replacing the old content with the new. If your able to, it could be worth sticking the code/content for the pagination in a separate file that is included and then your ajax can reflect the included file, only returning say the table with the new results instead of the whole page?

Comment: @Gavin Yes it works currently,just when I replace the filter content with the earlier one it doesn't and that's what i want to fix.I tried sending the paginated content also but,then it takes me to the process.php page which actually is for just processing and nothing for display.Can you clarify a bit more.Sorry but not good at ajax/jquery. Thanks

Comment: Your jQuery ajax is pointing to `process.php`. Looking at your PHP code, you are generating URL's that handle everything. As a result, you could simply hook a jQuery call to those. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comments.

You could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.paginate').live('click', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btnPage = $(this);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : btnPage.attr('href'),
            success : function(resp)
            {
                // replace current results with new results.
                $('#project_section').html(resp);
            },
            error : function()
            {
                window.location.href = btnPage.attr('href');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The above will replicate you clicking on each of the pagination links.

What I would advise to do next is to separate the PHP code and HTML that generates your "results" list into a separate file.

This way, on the page that displays the results, you can simply use `include('path-to-results-file.php');` which will work for non-ajax requests and then you could do:

**Process.php**

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    include('path-to-results-file.php');
    die();
}
```

The above would detect if an ajax request has been made and if so, instead of displaying the whole page including the results, it will simply display only the results and the pagination.

**Updated to include a better explanation**

Below is a VERY simple example of what I mean.

**Current process.php**

```
    <?
    // currently contains all of the code required
    // to query the database etc.
?>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <!-- header content -->
    <table>
    <?
        // currently contains all of the code required to display
        // the results table and pagination links.
    ?>
    </table>
    <!-- footer content -->
</body>
</html>
```

**New process.php**

```
<?
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
    {
        include('path-to-results-file.php');
        die();
    }
?>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <!-- header content -->
    <? include('path-to-results-file.php'); ?>
    <!-- footer content -->
</body>
</html>
```

**New path-to-results-file.php**

```
<?
    // currently contains all of the code required
    // to query the database etc.
?>
<table>
<?
    // currently contains all of the code required to display
    // the results table and pagination links.
?>
</table>
```

Now... When you go to `process.php` normally via your browser, or when javascript is disabled. It will simply work the same way it does without Javascript now.

When you go to `process.php` and then click on one of the pagination links (with javascript enabled), `process.php` will detect that you are using Ajax and only send back the table of results.

Comment: Thanks Gavin!!I got the jquery part,which will execute on the click of the page no links!Right?? But the second part of separation i did not get!! how can I keep the html and php code separately?Sorry I am not aware of any framework,neither using any.It would be great if you throw some light over it!!

Comment: Correct. This will replicate what you already have in place but by using Ajax instead. The problem you will find now, is that `#project_section` will contain the whole Page instead of just the changes you want. A solution, is to extract all of the code/content needed to create the results table and pagination and put it in a separate file. I'll update the answer to explain.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I will give it a try and get back if I need your help(I hope  don't after such a nice explanation)!! ;)

Comment: Hi Gavin I tried it and stuck at a point.I am not able to fix the url parameters and my $_PoST aray returned is passed as blank when I click on the pagination link.When I do a alert for this  `url : btnPage.attr('href')`,
I get `/RealEstate/process.php?page=3&ipp=2&venue=Array`.How can I resolve this?? Thanks

Comment: Did you say the script works without ajax as is? i.e. it works when you click on the links? $_POST returns blank because your not "posting" your "getting". `&venue=Array` is because your script is treating every post/get value as a string, where `venue` is an array.

Comment: Yes I get into the function and the url which is printed/echoed is also right,just that the parameter for array is returned blank on the script call.Initially I have the array(do i need to convert it to string?),but how can i pass it to the paginate link as it is build dynamically in the paginator class??sorry if I am asking for more.But its a bit urgent thats the reason.Short of time

Comment: I have tried separating the HTML and the PHP code but still I get the ENTIRE page.Anything I am missing??

Comment: Have you implemented the top of **new process.php** in my example above? There is code that detects the Ajax request and then includes the file that contains the HTML and PHP code.

Comment: Yes I have added that,but in my case its going in there for each request!!And I get a connection error for the `include` portion!!I have updated the question with my new files

Comment: Can you also include the errors you are getting when you update the question?

Comment: Its related to the DB connection as the file is included before it gets the query results in the HTML. `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\xampplite\htdocs\RealEstate\processRegion.php on line 12` and for other SQL functions like `mysql_query`

Comment: Stumbled upon these two threads which have similar issue addressed 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763280/pagination-not-working-when-adding-ajax   2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764067/ajax-pagination-adding-data-insted-of-replacing-data

Comment: Does the results and pagination work on the first load (without ajax)?

Comment: yes the classic PHP part works pretty well,just as I have filters and search functionality which has to work without a page refresh,I have to implement this.

Comment: Hi I need a bit of your help again.Your answer definitely helped me(accepted and upvoted) but now I am facing another issue here.After using `if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')`,when I click on a page link,I get the desired view of the paginated div but the page is reloaded in the back end for each click.(means if I check firebug all js,css files are reloaded and hence the links response very slow or sometimes even hang up the browser).It works fine when I am returning a page with no html other than the div.

Comment: Without seeing it in action, it's very difficult to explain. If possible, post a link to the page so we can see it in action.

Comment: Sorry gavin I have no access to any server,working on it on the localhost!! :( Still I appreciate you for the response.Thank you!!If any further details(apart from link) I would definitely do that!!