# Managing strings with ajax post request and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a check box based filter operation for a website.This has multiple checkboxes which filter a list of records on different parameters.Similar to what is done [here](http://www.proptiger.com/property-in-pune-real-estate.php).Now I have managed to achieve some success,and I have filtered the records based on first set of checkboxes.Here is the js function for it.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="checkbox1" value="<?php echo $suburb['suburb_name']?>" name="Suburb_check[]" onClick="changeResults();" onChange="" >
```

**Javascript:**

```
function changeResults(){
    var data = { 'venue[]' : []};
        $("input[name=Suburb_check[]]:checked").each(function() {                           var chck1 = $(this).val();
                data['venue[]'].push($(this).val());
                dataString =data['venue[]'.toString()].toString();
        });

    $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url : 'process.php',
   data : "dataString="+dataString,
   success : function(data){
                 $('#project_section').html(data); 
        }  
    }); 
}
```

What this does is **filters the records + loads the second set of check boxes**.1st set check box)=>**for Regions** and 2nd is =>**for Localities**
I have created an array to pass the check box values and then converted it to a string(**.toString**) and passed to the .php file.

Similarly I created a function for 2nd set of checkboxes.
**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="changeLocality();" id="localityCheck" value="<?php echo $locality['locality_name'];?>" name="Locality_check[]">
```

**JS**

```
function changeLocality(){  
    var dataLocality = {'locality[]' : []};         
        $("input[name=Locality_check[]]:checked").each(function() {         
        var chcklocal = $(this).val();              
        dataLocality['locality[]'].push($(this).val());
            localityString =dataLocality['locality[]'.toString()].toString();

        });

 $.ajax({
 type : 'POST',
 url : 'processLocality.php',
 data : "localityString="+localityString,
 success : function(dataLocality){
          $('#project_section').html(dataLocality);        // replace the contents coming from php file      
        }  
    });
}
```

Pass the values to a php file but when I try to get them using **$_POST**,the strings I get mixed into each other i.e the region values go into locality string and vice-versa(**Tried this using array with same result** so switched to strings).
I am not able to fix this.Why is this happening
This are the php files i post values to.
processLocality.php

```
<?php session_start();
include_once("includes/classes/db_connect.php");
include_once("pagination/paginator.class.php");
$pages = new Paginator();

$regions = "'".$_POST['dataString']."'";
echo $regions;
$arr = explode(",",$regions);
$getFormatedSuburb = implode("','",$arr);

$locality = "'".$_POST['localityString']."'";
echo $locality;
$arrLocal = explode(",",$locality);
$getFormatedLocality = implode("','",$arrLocal);

//Here I get the strings mixed with each other!!
 ?>
```

I have added some expression to the string for passing it to the IN clause of SQL query in the needed format.
Now the strings I get contains values from both regions and localities.I want both separately as they are two different **parameters for filtering records**

```
        Pune East,
        Pune West,        //1 and 2 are regions
         Aundh,
         Kalyaninagar     //3 and 4 are localities
```

Also,I would like to know is my approach correct.Any better way of achieving this?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Boil the code down and isolate the problem - noone is going through that much code.

Comment: @Repox Thanks for the inputs!! The reason for adding the details was I wanted to make sure I make my point very clear.I have updated the question.Hope the downvote goes by this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your selectors. Instead of this:

```
$("input[name=Suburb_check[]]:checked")
....
$("input[name=Locality_check[]]:checked")
```

Do this:

```
$("input[name=Suburb_check]:checked")
....
$("input[name=Locality_check]:checked")
```

Also the markup has to be in the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Suburb_check">
```

With the same name for each checkbox group. The name can not contain "[]"

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem and, seeing as we don't know what the HTML looks like, it's impossible to tell whether the current selectors are correct or not.

Comment: @JamWaffles Updated the question with HTML!

Comment: Updated answer. Your markup can't have "[]" in the name attributes

Comment: @endoalir Don't we add "[]" while passing the checkbox array in PHP??I did the same way for javascript!!Stupid I was!! Thanks for the answer!!upvoted and accepted!

Comment: Nah, it's an easy mistake sachin :)

Comment: @endoalir If possible can you have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928368/paginate-records-on-client-side-issue/10929242#comment14290891_10929242.I have posted a question regarding pagination issue.Thanks